# not redirecting properly with header

Tags: php, mysql

The deletion works and the page redirects but the url after deletion is `http://localhost:/manage_items.php?yesdelete=23` Why is that? It should be `manage_items.php`

```
while ($row = $get_products->fetch()) {
  $item_id =  $row['item_id'];
  $user_id =  $row['user_id'];
  $item_name = $row['item_name'];
  $date = $row['add_date'];
  $image = $row['photopath'];
  $products .= "<br/><img src = $image><img> Item ID: $item_id UserID: $user_id NAME: 
                  $item_name Added on: $date &nbsp
                  <a href='item_edit.php?pid=$item_id'>Edit</a>&nbsp 
                  <a href='manage_items.php?deleted=$item_id'>Delete</a>";
}

//delete Item

if(isset($_GET['deleted'])) {
   echo 'delete this product?'.$_GET['deleted'].'<a 
         href="manage_items.php?yesdelete='.$_GET['deleted'].'">Yes<a/> 
         / <a href ="manage_items.php">No</a>';
   exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
  $deleteid = $_GET['yesdelete'];
  $sql = $db->exec("DELETE FROM item WHERE `item_id` = '$deleteid' LIMIT 1");
  $image_delete = 'file_to/$deleteid';

  if(file_exists($image_delete)) {
    unlink($image_delete);
  }
  header("Location: manage_items.php");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: _1._ **your code is vulnerable to sql injection** _2._ **your code is vulnerable to XSS**

Comment: @NullPoiиteя yes I know but that's not what I'm concerned with at this point.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: What happened? Error? Nothing? Weirdness? I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Try a different browser and see if it does the same. Nothing in your code suggests that the query string should persist across redirects. You could also try monitoring the network requests / responses in your browser's *Net* developer console tab

Comment: Does it happen with all browsers?

Comment: @Dude I didn't see anything either but all I get is a blank page. The deletion works but just wont display the `manage_items.php` page

Comment: Does it go to the manage_items.php page? If it does, you will have to check the script on that page, because the first page is working fine.

Comment: have you turned off  off error and warning ?

Comment: you are using get method

Comment: @dhpratik could i know in what context you wrote this  comment ?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos happens in firefox as well. I end up with `manage_items.php?yesdelete=23`

Comment: if(isset($_GET['yesdelete']))

Comment: @dhpratik yes i can see but whats wrong with that ?

Comment: @dhpratik yes, its right there in the code

Comment: with `?> <?php` in your code block this is never going to work unless you use buffering.

Comment: @bansi OP says that the redirect works, and this is obviously just in the code here, not their actual code.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos right, code works.No `headers already sent` message. Made sure of no white space as well

Comment: @rogerthat I edited your code here, so that people stop thinking that you have this: `?>  <?php` in your code. Please confirm that this is true.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos its true. I've tried to say it a couple times

Comment: @rogerthat then post whole code of your page

Comment: @rogerthat I was unable to reproduce in my localhost. Please include some PHP version info (and other information about your testing environment) in your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Your problem which is too localize and probably because of typo so not useful for feature visitors

Answer (score 0):

header must be called before any kind of output went to browser to work properly, even I don't see whole code I see that you're outputting blank string in:

```
  ?>
  <?php
```

remove all such places and possible other where output can be done - then redirection will work

also, I really suggest you to use proper redirection:

```
function redirect($url)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
    {
        if (strtoupper($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) == 'HTTP/1.1')
            @header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other', true, 303);
        else
            @header('HTTP/1.0 302 Found', true, 302);
        @header('Location: ' . $url);
        @header('Content-type: text/html');
    }

    echo '<html><head><title>Redirect</title><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL='.htmlspecialchars($url).'"></head><body>'.
        '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($url).'">Click here</a>'.
        '</body></html>';
    @ob_flush();
    exit();
}
```

Comment: The OP has already confirmed that the redirect occurs. This is not a *headers already sent* issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a case of header already sent case.

You have to do the following.

1. Remove the code block.

   `?>
   <?php`
2. Remove any space and newlines before the first `<?`
3. Remove the last `?>` or at-least make sure there is no space or newline after that.
4. you can use output buffering [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), [ob_end_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php)

Edit: you are also sending html before redirect. Here i have re-arranged your code. I have moved the delete block to the beginning.

```
<?php
//delete Item

if(isset($_GET['yesdelete']))
{
    $deleteid = $_GET['yesdelete'];

    $sql = $db->exec("DELETE FROM item WHERE `item_id` = '$deleteid' LIMIT 1");

    $image_delete = 'file_to/$deleteid';

    if(file_exists($image_delete))
    {
        unlink($image_delete);

    }
    header("Location: manage_items.php");
    exit();
}
while ($row = $get_products->fetch())
{
    $item_id =  $row['item_id'];
    $user_id =  $row['user_id'];
    $item_name = $row['item_name'];
    $date = $row['add_date'];
    $image = $row['photopath'];
    $products .= "<br/><img src = $image><img> Item ID: $item_id UserID: $user_id NAME: 
                  $item_name Added on: $date &nbsp
                  <a href='item_edit.php?pid=$item_id'>Edit</a>&nbsp 
                  <a href='manage_items.php?deleted=$item_id'>Delete</a>";
}
if(isset($_GET['deleted']))
{
    echo 'delete this product?'.$_GET['deleted'].'<a 
           href="manage_items.php?yesdelete='.$_GET['deleted'].'">Yes<a/> 
           / <a href ="manage_items.php">No</a>';
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your answer suggests nothing useful.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos 1st item from this post actually fix of the error

Comment: @IlyaBursov you tested?

Comment: @IlyaBursov The redirect works, it hasn't sent the headers. Take some time to read the comments. I know, because I was here before this question was edited for the first time (that the two php code blocks were merged into one)

Comment: I dont think that's the problem. In the past I've had many code blocks in my page and redirects have always worked well.

Comment: @rogerthat I meant the two blockquotes of this question that you initially had.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos oh, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem. It was in my session block at the top of the page

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))

{
header("Location: yackimo_register_form.php");

exit();
}
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];
echo "";<<<------------
```

Bad habit

Comment: I'm glad you found it. Just make sure that you actually add all suspicious code next time.